# How to save a pdf with the objects property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdfsharp

I am using PdfSharp to generate reports. I would like to save the generated reports with the "JobName" property of the object. Adding the current date/time would be great to. the property I want to use is "job.JobName"

```
 // Save the document...
           const string filename = @"C:\Users\texas_000\Desktop\TexasExterior\TexasExterior\JobSetupPdfs\HelloWorld.pdf";

            document.Save(filename);
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem.?

Comment: instead of saving the pdf with "HelloWorld.pdf" . I need to save it as job.JobName + job.JobDate.pdf    job.JobName & job.JobDate would be the the currently selected job data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var filename = string.Format(@"C:\Users\texas_000\Desktop\TexasExterior\TexasExterior\JobSetupPdfs\{0}{1}.pdf", job.JobName, job.JobDate);
    document.Save(filename);
```